# Webnovel where the main character goes to India and protects a girl who gives him power

Tags: story-identification, novel

In this particular story, the main character goes to India. While he is there he protects an Indian girl who has powers of Shiva/Rudra, but the girl ultimately dies and she gives some of her power to the main character while dying.

I think maybe it's a Korean or Chinese novel. It's like powers/incarnation of god in a modern-day world like *Solo leveling*.

Edit-The novel also had guilds and one Guild was trying to protect the girl while other Indian guilds were trying to kill her.

Edit-I found the novel when i was browsing. Its called "The World Turned into a Game After I Woke up"

Comment: You mention a Webnovel which is usually just text, manga which are generally Japanese comic books, and then a Korean or Chinese novel. Can you clarify whether this is text or images?

Comment: Text. I dont why the question has a manga tag i only added story identification.

Comment: You described it as a "manga" in the body of the text, so it looks like someone "corrected" it for you. Can I get you to go through [this list of prompts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if that elicits any further details you can [edit] in? It seems like a fairly unique story, so hopefully we can find it for you. Do you have particular sites you frequent often?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I usually browse wuxiaworld and web novel pub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The querent identified the story as [*The World Turned into a Game After I Woke up*](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-world-turned-into-a-game-after-i-woke-up/).

> On that fateful day, a voice in the sky told everyone on Earth that the world they called home has just been part of some sort of simulation.
>
> The next thing everyone knew, the world was rife with monsters and dungeons and resurrecting immortal devas!
>
> I spent eleven years in that world as a deva, crawling and clawing my way through the dirt trying to make a name for myself. I wanted another chance at this, I made so many mistakes, I could have done so much better.
>
> But after all that wishing for a new beginning ended in a very bad ending… I was finally given that chance. I just had to be tortured by some smartass…
>
> But I’m going to make the most out of this! I’ll become the strongest deva out there! And this time, I’ll have my revenge!